# Consecutive sum of integers is multiple of N - My code is correct but too slow

Tags: c++, arrays, performance

This program is written in C++

The purpose of this program is to read set of numbers that is <= 100,000 into an array and then sum up consecutive numbers and test if they are a multiple of N.  Once sum % N == 0 is true then the program outputs the indices of i and j showing exactly from which positions i through j sum to be a multiple of N.  There could be multiple solutions, but only one is required so once a solution is found the bool variable is set to true to exit the loop.

My code does correctly calculate a single solution, however, it doesn't do it efficiently enough.  Furthermore, I am told that the use of an unsigned sum variable is not necessary as a standard int sum variable is enough to satisfy the requirements of this program.  Without the unsigned version of sum I encountered overflow that seemed to ruin my calculations as each test case does contain 100,000 combinations of integers.

Any help or direction is appreciated.  Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int testCases = 0, n = 0;
    
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    
    const int arraySize = 100000;
    
    int array[arraySize];
    
    ofstream outFile ("output.txt");
    
    ifstream inFile ("input.txt");
    
    inFile >> testCases;
    
    while(testCases > 0)
    {
        
        bool found = false;
        
        inFile >> n;
                
        for(int a = 0; a < n; a++)
            inFile >> array[a];
    
        for(int i = 0; i < n && !found; ++i)
            for(int j = i; j < n && !found; ++j)
            {
                sum = 0;
            
                for(int d = i; d <= j; d++)
                    sum += array[d];
                                
                if (sum % n == 0)
                {
                    outFile << i << ' ' << j << endl;
                    found = true;
                }
                    
             }
        testCases--;
    }
            
    outFile.close();
    inFile.close();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like the same homework problem as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69674853/finding-number-of-pairs-product-of-whose-indices-is-divisible-by-another-number). Maybe you folks can get together.

Comment: Why do you need a nested `for` loop to solve this problem?  Couldn't you make a single pass through the loop and use some logic in each pass, thus making this an `O(n)` complexity?

Comment: If your code is too slow, you usually have to many iterations. Rethink the approach to your solution, it is not a code problem.  (Also note this is why I don't like competitve coding sites, they teach you problem solving, but not how to write good software)

Comment: Maybe [this helps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269916/what-is-sliding-window-algorithm-examples)

Comment: What are the constraints on input data? There is a crafty way to do it with `o(n)` or `o(n long n)` complexity depending on those constraints.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk K. Polk - After reading your reply to him it does give me some ideas.  Thank you.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I may not need a nested for loop, I'll try to see if I can reduce it.  Thank you.

Comment: @MarekR The only restraints are that there will be at most 10 test cases and 2 <= n <= 100000

Comment: just to be clear: `n` defines two things: modulo operation and size of the array. There is no other value distinguishing those two.

Comment: @MarekR Yes, you are correct!

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to read the entire input file before you begin processing?

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your program is that it has high time complexity.
Each test case run two nested `for` loops `n` times. This means that your program has `O(n^2)` complexity. This is quite poor for this problem.

Now the trick here is to track indexes for partial sums modulo `n` in some data structure. When you adding new item `x` to this data structure first you should check if it already contains element for partial sum equal to `(n - x) % n`, if it has then you will be able to find begin and end index for your solution.
This approach will give you `o(n)` complexity or `o(n log n)` depending what kind of data structure you will use.

I will give just this hint (which IMO is more then enough to find solution), since IMO giving ready solution is not a good teaching practice. If you have more question let me know.

Offtopic: do not use `std::endl` it slows down IO operations a lot. Replace it with `'\n'`.